# Inserting values into another table using a conditional statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to insert values to another table using conditional statement but the values does not insert inside the table.

```
<?php 
  if($_POST['save'])
  {
     $pr_no      = $_POST['pr_no'];
     $s = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT purchase_no FROM `sms_request` WHERE purchase_no = '".$pr_no."'");
     if(mysqli_num_rows($s) > 0)
     {
         echo"<script type='text/javascript'>
              alert('Purchase No. Existed!');
              window.location.href = 'sms_supply management.php';
              </script>                 ";
     }
     else
     {
        $fcluster   = $_POST['fund_cluster'];
        $osection   = $_POST['office_section'];
        $pr_no      = $_POST['pr_no'];
        $rcode      = $_POST['responsibility_code'];
        $desig      = $_POST['desig'];
        $requester  = $_POST['requester'];
        $loc        = $_POST['loc'];
        $purpose    = $_POST['prpose'];
        $ename      = $_POST['entity_name'];
        $date       = $_POST['date'];
        $dateA      = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));
        $radioo     = $_POST['supply_type'];
        $ins = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO sms_purchaserecord(purchase_no, supply_type) VALUES ('".$pr_no."', '".$radioo."')");
        $insS = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO sms_ris(purchase_no, ris_num) VALUES ('".$pr_no."', '".$pr_no."')");
        $insert = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO sms_request(purchase_no,sms_request.date, entity_name, fund_cluster, office_section, responsibility_code, purpose, stat) VALUES ('".$pr_no."','".$dateA."','".$ename."', '".$fcluster."', '".$osection."', '".$rcode."','".$purpose."', '1')");
        $inS = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO sms_iar(iar_num, purchase_no) VALUES ('".$pr_no."', '".$pr_no."')");

        $select = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT request_IDnum FROM sms_request WHERE purchase_no = '".$pr_no."'");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
           $rnum = $row['request_IDnum'];
        }
        $select2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM sms_branchloc WHERE loc_ID_no = '".$loc."'");
        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($select2)){
           $loc_num = $row1['loc_ID_no'];
        }
        if ($rnum != NULL AND $loc_num != NULL){
           $insert2 = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO sms_requester(request_IDnum, name, loc_ID_no, position) VALUES ('".$rnum."', '".$requester."', '".$loc_num."', '".$desig."')");
        }

        if ($radioo == 'expandable'){
           $insertI = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO inventory_status(stock_prop_num, description, unit, quantity, price) VALUES ('".$pr_num."','".$unit."','".$desc."','".$qty."','".$cost."')");
        }
  // If I choose expandable on the radio button it will insert into the inventory_status table
        foreach ($_POST['sp_num'] as $row=>$sp_numm) {
              $sp_num = $sp_numm;
              $unit = $_POST['unt'][$row];
              $desc = $_POST['sdesc'][$row];
              $qty = $_POST['sqty'][$row];
              $cost = $_POST['cost'][$row];

              $query = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO sms_supply (supply_qty,purchase_no,unit_cost,supply_unit,supply_desc,stockproperty_num) VALUES ('".$qty."','".$pr_no."', '".$cost."', '".$unit."','".$desc."', '".$sp_num."')");

            }    
             echo"<script type='text/javascript'>
                  alert('Purchase Request Save.');
                  window.location.href = 'sms_supply management.php';
                  </script>";
      }
  }
```

What I wanted to do is if I choose expandable on the radio button it will insert the values into the inventory_status table. The block of code that didn't work is

```
if ($radioo == 'expandable')
{
    $insertI = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO 
    inventory_status(stock_prop_num, description, unit, quantity, price) VALUES('".$pr_num."', '".$unit."','".$desc."', '".$qty."', '".$cost."')");
```

Do I need to connect the 2 tables with a primary key and foreign key?

Comment: Your column order is `description, unit` but your value order is in reverse `'".$unit."','".$desc."'`?

Comment: @Sean thanks but how do I make it insert to the inventory_status table?